# I am trying to remove the bed-each from my Microsoft Word application

Tags: microsoft-word

Every time when I attempt to cut and paste a hyperlink from the Internet onto my Microsoft Word it becomes embedded and I get the whole URL.  Is there any way that I can reverse this?

Thank you for any help

Comment: Please ask this at superuser.com - they will be able to help with application-related issues like this.

Answer (score 2):

Edit -> Paste Special -> Unformatted Text